Proof strategies for dealing with limits and continuity questions.
Background
The following Definitions, Theorem, Lemma and Example below are taken from How to Prove it A structured Approach 2nd Edition, by Daniel J. Velleman.  The Rule of inference table is taken from Discrete Mathematics 8th Edition, by: Richard Johnsonbaugh, Calculus 3rd edition by:  Michael Spivak, Fundamentals of Real Analysis by: Sterling K. Berberian, Analysis on Manifolds by: James R. Munkres.
Definition of Limit: $\forall \epsilon >0,\quad( \exists \delta >0\wedge 0<|x-x_0|<\delta \rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\epsilon)$
Definition of continuity: $\forall \epsilon >0,\quad( \exists \delta >0\wedge 0<|x-x_0|<\delta \rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon)$
Definition for a set to be of Measure zero:  Let $A$ be a subset of R$^n$.  We say $A$ has measure zero in R$^n$ if for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a covering $Q_1,Q_2,$... of $A$ by countably many rectangles such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}v(Q_i)<\epsilon$$.
If this inequality holds, we often say that the total volume of the rectangles $Q_1,Q_2$,.... is less than $\epsilon$.
Theorem 7:  Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions which are continuous on $[a,b]$ and that  $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ to $f.$ Then $f$ is also continuous on $[a,b]$.

Proof:  For each $x$ in $[a,b]$ we must prove that $f$ is continuous at $x$.  We will deal only with $x$ in $(a,b)$; the case $a=a$ and $x=b$ requires the usual simple modifications.
$\quad$  Let $\epsilon>0$, Since $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$, there is some $n$ suchh that
$$|f(y)-f_n(y)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}\quad\quad\text{for all y in }[a,b]$$
In particular, for all $h$ such that $x+h$ is in $[a,b]$, we have
$$(1)\quad |f(x)-f_n(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3},$$
$$(2)\quad |f(x+h)-f_n(x+h)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3},$$
Now $f_n$ is continuous, so there is some $\delta>0$ such that for $|h|<\delta$ we have
$$(3)\quad |f_n(x)-f_n(x+h)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3},$$
Thus, if $|h|<\delta$, then
$$|f(x)-f(x+h)|$$
$$\quad\quad=|f(x+h)-f_n(x+h)+f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)+f_n(x)-f(x)|$$
$$\quad\quad\leq|f(x+h)-f_n(x+h)|+|f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f(x)|$$
$$\quad\quad<\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}$$
$$\quad\quad=\epsilon$$
This proves that $F$ is continuous at $x$.

8.1.11 Lemma: Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,\rho)$ be given metric spaces and suppose that $(X,d)$ is totally bounded.  Let $(f_N)$ be an equi-uniformly continuouse sequence in $C(X,Y)$ and suppose there exists a dense subset $A$ of $X$ such that $(f_n(x))$ is Cauchy for each $x\in A.$.  Then $(f_n)$ is uniformly Cauchy on $X$.

Proof:  We observe first that if $f:X\to Y$ is uniformly continuous, then $f(X)$ is a totally bounded subset of $Y$. For, let $(y_n)$ be any sequence in $f(X)$ and, for each $n$, choose $x_n\in X$ so that $f(x_n)=y_n$.  Since $X$ is totally bounded, the sequence $(x_n)$ has a Cauchy subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ and since $f$ is uniformly continuous it follows that $(f(x_{n_k}))=(y_{n_k})$ is Cauchy in $Y$.  Thus, every sequence in $f(X)$ has a Cauchy subsequence, consequewntly $f(X)$ is totally bounded.  In particular,
$$\text{diam }f(X)<+\infty$$
that is, $f$ is bounded.  Thus,
$$f:X\to Y\text{ uniformly continuous }\Rightarrow f\in C(X,Y)\cap B(X,Y),$$
so that the metric
$$D(f,g)=\sup_{x\in X} \rho(f(x),g(x))$$
on $B(X,Y)$ is defined for all pairs $f,g$ of uniformly continuous functions $X\to Y $; in other words, $D$ defines metric on the set $C_u(X,Y)$ of all uniformly continuous functions $X\to Y$, convergence relative to $D$ signifying uniform convergence.
$\quad$ With $(f_n)$ as in the statement of the lemma, we are to show that $D(f_m,f_n)\to 0$ as $m,n\to \infty$.  Given any $\epsilon>0$, we seek an index $N$ such that
$$m,n\geq N\Rightarrow D(f_m,f_n)\leq\epsilon.$$
By the assumed equi-uniform continuity of the sequence, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that
$$(1)\quad\quad d(x,x')<\delta\Rightarrow \rho(f_n(x),f_n(x'))<\frac{\epsilon}{3}\text{ for all }n.$$
Let $x_1,\ldots,x_r$ be a $\frac{\delta}{2}-$net in the totally bounded space $X$; by the density of $A$, there exists points $a_1,\ldots,a_r$ in $A$ such that
$$d(a_i,x_i)<\frac{\delta}{2}\text{ for }i=1,\ldots,r,$$
and it follows from the triangle inequality that
$$(2)\quad\quad a_1,\ldots,a_r\text{ is a }\delta-\text{net in }X.$$
By the hypothesis on $A$, we know that each of the finitely many sequences $(f_n(a_i)) (i=1,\ldots,r)$ is Cauchy in $Y$, therefore there exists an index $N$ such that
$$(3)\quad\quad m,n\geq N\Rightarrow \rho(f_m(a_i),f_n(a_i))<\frac{\epsilon}{3}\text{ for }i=1,\ldots,r.$$
Fix a pair of indices $m,n\geq N$ and fix a point $x\in X$; we need only show that $p(f_m(x),f_n(x))<\epsilon.$
$\quad$ By $(2)$, there exists an index $j(1\leq j\leq r)$ such that
$$(4)\quad\quad d(x,a_j)<\delta$$
Then
$$\rho(f_m(x),f_n(x))\leq \rho(f_m(x),f_m(a_j))+\rho(f_m(a_j),f_n(f_j))+\rho(f_n(a_j),f_n(x)),$$
where the middle term on the right side of the inequality is $<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ by $(3)$, while the first and third terms on the righrt are $<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ by $(4)$ and $(1)$, thus $\rho(f_m(x),f_n(x))<\epsilon$ as desired.

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textit{Rule of Inference} & Name \\ \hline
\frac{\forall x P(x)}{\therefore P(d) \text{ if } d\in D} & \text{ Universal instantiation  }  \\ \hline
\frac{P(d) \text{ for every } d\in D}{\therefore \forall x P(x)}& \text{ Universal generalization  } \\ \hline
\frac{\exists x P(x)}{\therefore P(d) \text{ if } d\in D}& \text{ Existential instantiation  }  \\ \hline
\frac{P(d) \text{ for some } d\in D}{\therefore \exists x P(x)}& \text{ Existential generalization  }  \\ \hline
\end{array}$
Note: $D$ denote the domain of discourse.
Example Theorem:  Suppose $F$ and $G$ are familiees of sets and $F\cap G\neq \emptyset$.  Prove that $\cap F\subset \cup G$.
Step 1:
Scratch work
Our first step in analyzing the logical form of the goal is to write out the meaning of the subset symbol, which gives us the staement $\forall x(x\in \cap F\to x\in \cup G)$.  We could go further with this analysis by writing out the definitions of union an dintersection, but the part of the analysis that we have already done will be enough to allow us to decide how to get started on the proof.  The definitions of union and intersection will be needed later in the proof, but we will wait until they are needed before filling them in.  When analyzing the logical forms of givens and goals in order to figure out a proof, it is usally best to do only as much of the analysis as is neded to determine the next setp of the proof.  Going further with the logical analysis usually just introduces unnecessary complications without providing any benefit.
Because the goal means $\forall x(x\in \cap F\to x\in \cup G)$, we let $x$ be arbitrary, assume $x\in \cap F$, and try to prove $x\in \cup G$.
$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textit{Givens} & \textit{Goals} \\ \hline
F\cap G\neq\emptyset & x\in \cup G  \\ \hline
x\in \cap F &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$
The new goal means $\exists A\in G(x\in A)$, so to prove it we should try to find a value that wil "work" for $A$.  Just looking at thegoal doesn't make it clear how to choose $A$, so we look more closely at the givens.  We begin by writing them out logical symbols:
Step 2:
$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textit{Givens} & \textit{Goals} \\ \hline
\exists A(A\in F\cap G) & \exists A\in G(x\in A)  \\ \hline
\forall A\in F(x\in A) &  \\ \hline
\end{array}$
The second given starts with $\forall A$, so we may not be able to use this given until a likely value to plug in for $A$ pops up during the course of the proof.  In particular, we should keep in mind that if we ever come across an element of $F$ while trying to figure out thte proof, we can pug it in for $A$ in the second given and conclude that it contains $x$ as an element.  The first given, however, starts with $\exists A$, so we should use it immediately.  It says that there is some object that is an element of $F\cap G$.  By existential instantiation, we can introduce a name, say $A_0$, for this object.  Thus, we can treat $A_0\in F\cap G$ as a given from now on.  Because we can now have a name, $A_0$, for a particular eleemnt of $F\cap G$, it would be redudant to continue to discuss the given statement $\exists A(A\in F\cap G)$, so we will drop it from our list of givens.  Since our new given $A_0\in F\cap G$ means $A_0\in F$ and $A_0\in G$, we now have the following situation:
Step 3:
$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textit{Givens} & \textit{Goals} \\ \hline
A_0\in F & \exists A\in G(x\in A)  \\ \hline
A_0\in G &  \\ \hline
 \forall A\in F(x\in A)&  \\ \hline
\end{array}$
IF you've been paying close atttention, you should know what the next step should be.  We decide before to keep our eyes open for any elements of $F$ that might come up during the proof, because we might want to plug them in for $A$ in the last given.  An element of $F$ has come up:  $A_0$!  Plugging $A_0$ in for $A$ in the last given, we can conclude that $x\in A_0$.  Any concludsion can be treated in the future as givens, so you can ad this statement to the givens column if you like.
Remember that we decide to look at the givens becuase we didn't know what value to assign to $A$ in the goal.  What we nee is a value for $A$ that is in $G$  and that will make the statement $x\in A$ come out true.  Has this consideration of the givens suggested a value to use for $A$? Yes! Use $A=A_0$.
Although we translated the given statements $x\in \cap F, x\in \cup G$, and $F\cap G\neq\emptyset$ into logical symbols in order to figure out how to use them in the proof, these translations are not usallly written out when the proof is written in final form.  In the final proof we just write these statements in their original form an dleave it to the reader of the proof to work out their logical forms in order to follow our reasoning.
Example Theorem:  Suppose $F$ and $G$ are familiees of sets and $F\cap G\neq \emptyset$.  Prove that $\cap F\subset \cup G$.
Solution

Proof:  Suppose $x\in \cap F$.  Since $F\cap G\neq \emptyset$, we can let $A_0$ be an eleemnt of $F\cap G$.  Thus $A_0\in F$ and $A_0\in G$.  Since $x\in \cap F$ and $A_0\in F$, it follows that $x\in A_0$.  But we also know that $A_0\in G$, so we can conclude that $x\in \cup G$.

Questions:
I want to ask that when we are ask in the cases of $(a)-(e)$ below to prove existence of limits/continuity or when ask to prove a partcular limit/continuity equals to certain value say $L$ as above.  It often begins in either the following:
$(1)$  Let $\epsilon$ be arbitarry, or
$(2)$  Let $\epsilon=\epsilon_0$ after finding out what the $\epsilon_0$, should be
then the prover would exhibit a $\delta$ depending on the given $\epsilon$ like in the case of $(2)$.
$(a)$ showing existence of limits for functions or for sequences
$(b)$ computation of limits for functions or for sequences
$(c)$ showing a set has measure zero
$(d)$ Showing existence of integrals or of improper integrals
$(e)$  Proving the existence of limits/conftinuity/convergence for sequences of functions according to some definition and then having to breaking up $\epsilon$ into $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ type arguments.
What I would like to know from the viewpoint of symbolic logic, is the proof strategy universal instantiation follow by Existential generalization?  I tried looking at various symbolic logic and math proof writing texts.  The topic of how to deal with proving limits and continuity questions are presented, but I was not able to find specific mention of prove strategies.  I am guessing it is universal intantiation for the cases of $(a)-(e)$ above when trying to do $(1)$ and $(2)$ above. In all the cases above from $(a)$ to $(e)$, especially $(c),(e)$, $\epsilon$ need to be modified, but then also delta need to either be modified or is given according to some definition.  I also tried searching on MSE, but I was not able to find a past post that answered the question.
Thank you in advance

An argument that starts off with "Let $\epsilon \dots$, then exhibits a $\delta$, and eventually concludes from this $\forall \epsilon,\exists \delta$ is using universal generalization and existential generalization. This is how the existence and value of a limit is proved. Any proof that starts off by (2) is not proving the existence or value of a limit. That is the sort of beginning one would see if the existence or value of the limit is known, and is being applied to prove something else. Thus (2) is using universal instanciation, and will follow with existential instanciation on $\delta$.

@PaulSinclair Sorry for my super late reply.  I  was recovering from the flu and I was not able to be on the computer for the entiere week.  I edited my post after reading what you wrote.  I went trhough the different instances where $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs are presented.  I think they range the entire gamut of various types of questions, they all implicitly or explicitly want the reader to show for all $\epsilon$ there exists some $\delta$.... The thing is the books not only not state which quantifier proof strategies are not used, but in the cases of using....

@PaulSinclair definitions to show a sequences of funcctions or convergence of sequences by breaking up $\epsilon$, while either assumming some $\delta$ is founded, or again also needing to modified the found $\delta$.  Which proof strategies are employed is not discussed.  I am wondering if you can elaboarated more on which ones in the above cases $(a)-(e)$ uses which rules of inference according to the table I cited above.  If you think it is too long, can you write it as an answer.  I think this would be good for the MSE community as a reference.    Thank you in advance.

The proof strategy to show $\forall x, P(x)$ is to suppose $x$ is an arbitrary value about which nothing is known. Then demonstrate that $P(x)$ is true, and use universal generalization to conclude $\forall x, P(x) \implies Q(x)$. The proof strategy to show $\exists x, P(x)$ is demonstrate that $P(d)$ is true for some particular value $d$, then use existential generalization to conclude $\exists x, P(x)$.

To prove $\forall x, \exists y, P(x,y)$, you applies these in detail: (1) assume $x$ arbitrary and prove $\exists y, P(x,y)$. Which you do by the second stratery: demonstrate  some $d$ with $P(x,d)$ true for your arbitrary $x$. By existential generalization, conclude $\exists y, P(x,y)$, then by universal generalization conclude $\forall x, \exists y, P(x,y)$. Similar remarks hold for proving $\exists x, \forall y$, or $\forall x, \forall y$ or $\exists x, \exists y$, or all variations with more variables. All of these proofs you do are following exactly that.

In your example, you claim it is given that $x \in \bigcap F$. This is not correct. What is given is $\exists x, x \in F\cap G$. Even when $\bigcap F = \emptyset$, this result still holds. The proof strategy is $\bigcap F \subseteq x \subseteq \bigcup G$.

@PaulSinclair I copied out the complete scratch work from Velleman's text of his example. I just want to make sure I am not misunderstanding or that you pointing out my misunderstanding might have to do my misreading of his scratch work.   Also I want to make sure I am understandign you correcly. If we have a theorem where the conclusion is of the form $\forall x\exists y P(x,y)$, we apply universal generalization to $x$ to get $P(x,y)$, the existential generaliation after finding suitable $y$ say $y_0$ to let $y=y_0$ to get $P(x,y_0)$.  The other thing is when you stated in your first...

@PaulSinclair .... "Any proof that starts off by (2) is not proving the existence or value of a limit. That is the sort of beginning one would see if the existence or value of the limit is known, and is being applied to prove something else." What did you mean by that?  Also, are there cases where we have cases of (2) in epsilon delta proofs?  Lastly, in the casese where $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$-type arguments are used, it is still in the format of $\forall x\exists y P(x,y)$ appears in the conclusion?  In $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$-type arguments, it is a bit more confusing, because the prover is....

No, you apply existential generalization first to get $\exists y, P(x,y)$ where $x$ is still a constant. Then you apply universal generalization to get $\forall x,\exists y,P(x,y)$. In applying these generalization, you work from the inside out, not the outside in.

@PaulSinclair ...suppose to use some preexisting definition, and assume that $\delta$ is given or it gets modified, then modified $\epsilon$ by breaking it up. In those circumstances, the ttatement $\forall \epsilon \exists \delta P(\epsilon,\delta)$, the $\forall \delta$ seem to shifted to the hypothesis, so existential instantiation gets applied instead and not existential generalization.

@PaulSinclair I just respond to your comment as you were replying.  Can you explain to me what you meant by (2) and also is what you say applying to multiple quantifier from inside to outside apply to what you said for (2) and also in the case of $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ type arguments.

In the proof of Theorem 7, you start off knowing the following facts by the conditions on the theorem:$$\forall n\in\Bbb N, \forall x\in [a,b], \forall\epsilon > 0,\exists \delta > 0, \forall y\in [a,b], |y-x| < \delta \implies |f_n(y) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon$$(for all $n, f_n$ is continuous on $[a,b]$) and $$\forall \epsilon > 0,\exists N \in \Bbb N, \forall x \in [a,b], \forall n \ge N, |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$$ ($f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$). The proof starts off by instantiating these known facts to demonstrate the existence of the needed $\delta$ to prove $f$ is continuous.

@underflow Velleman says if we have a conclusion of the form $\forall x\exists y P(x,y)$ that entire statement would be part of the goal, and then he would break up that statements into $\forall x,, \exists y, P(x,y)$, and try to apply the appropiate rule of inference as proof strategies to each of those three statements, by looking at what is in the givens of the problem. It gets confusing when the theorem gets more complicated in the sense of theorem at the end of a real analysis course where the bit about how to treat the $\delta$ in proofs as part of the hypothesis of the theorem or....

@underflow .... as part of the conculsion where existen generalization is applied. An added difficulty of confusion is where $\epsilon$ need to be modifed.

FYI, your Existential Instantiation should be $\frac{\exists x P(x)}{\therefore \text{ for some }d\in D, P(d)}$, not $\frac{\exists x P(x)}{\therefore P(d) \text{ if } d\in D}$

@PaulSinclair is the reader to treat the conclusion of theorem 7 as:  $\forall \epsilon > 0,\exists N \in \Bbb N, \forall x \in [a,b], \forall n \ge N, |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$, and use universal and existential generalization?  Even though we are suppose to know th e following fact: $\forall n\in\Bbb N, \forall x\in [a,b], \forall\epsilon > 0,\exists \delta > 0, \forall y\in [a,b], |y-x| < \delta \implies |f_n(y) - f_n(x)| < \epsilon$.    Also when you say that the proof starts off by "instantiating", you don't mean in the sense of existential or universal instantiation?

Here is where the instantiations and generalizations occur in the proof of

Theorem 7:  Suppose that $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions which are continuous on $[a,b]$ and that  $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly on $[a,b]$ to $f.$ Then $f$ is also continuous on $[a,b]$.

As I noted in the comment, the conditions on this theorem are:

The $f_n$ are all continuous on $[a,b]$:
$$\forall n_1\in\Bbb N, \forall x_1\in [a,b], \forall\epsilon_1 > 0,\exists \delta_1 > 0, \\\forall y_1\in [a,b], |y_1-x_1| < \delta_1 \implies |f_{n_1}(y_1) - f_{n_1}(x_1)| < \epsilon_1\tag{1}$$

and

The sequence $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$: $$\forall \epsilon_2 > 0,\exists N_2 \in \Bbb N, \forall x_2 \in [a,b], \forall n_2 \ge N, |f_{n_2}(x_2) - f(x_2)| < \epsilon_2\tag{2}$$

What needs to be proved is $f$ is continuous:
$$\forall x \in [a,b],\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, \forall y \in [a,b], |y-x| < \delta \implies |f(y) - f(x)| < \epsilon$$
Now "for all"s commute with each other: $\forall x,\forall y, P(x,y) \iff \forall y,\forall x, P(x,y)$ (similarly $\exists x\exists y \iff \exists y\exists x$, but $\forall x\exists y$ is not the same as$\exists y\forall x$). So we can equivalently prove
$$\forall \epsilon > 0,\forall x \in [a,b], \exists \delta > 0, \forall y \in [a,b], |y-x| < \delta \implies |f(y) - f(x)| < \epsilon\tag{3}$$

Proof:  For each $x$ in $[a,b]$ we must prove that $f$ is continuous at $x$.  We will deal only with $x$ in $(a,b)$; the case $a=a$ and $x=b$ requires the usual simple modifications. [Introduction of arbitrary constant $x\in[a,b]$ to prove $\forall x\in [a,b]$ in (3)]
$\quad$  Let $\epsilon>0$ [introduction of arbitrary constant $\epsilon$ to prove $\forall\epsilon$ in (3)], Since $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$, there is some $n$ such that
$$|f(y)-f_n(y)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}\quad\quad\text{for all y in }[a,b]$$
[Instantiation of $\forall\epsilon_2\exists N_2\forall n_2$ in (2). With $\epsilon_2 = \frac{\epsilon}3$, $N_2$ is not explicitly needed, so it isn't mentioned, and $n_2 = n$.] In particular, for all $h$ such that $x+h$ is in $[a,b]$ , we have
$$(1)\quad |f(x)-f_n(x)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3},$$
[Instantiation of $y_2 = x$ in (2)]
$$(2)\quad |f(x+h)-f_n(x+h)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3},$$
[Instantiation of $y_2 = x + h$ in (2)]
Now $f_n$ is continuous, so there is some $\delta>0$ such that for $|h|<\delta$ we have
$$(3)\quad |f_n(x)-f_n(x+h)|<\frac{\epsilon}{3},$$
[Instantiation of $\epsilon_1 = \frac\epsilon 3, \delta_1 = \delta, n_1 = n, x_1 = x, y_1 = x+h$ from (1), demonstration of the existence of $\delta$]
Thus, if $|h|<\delta$ [introduction of constants $x$ and $y = x+h$ to prove $\forall x, \forall y$ in (3)], then
$$|f(x)-f(x+h)|$$
$$\quad\quad=|f(x+h)-f_n(x+h)+f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)+f_n(x)-f(x)|$$
$$\quad\quad\leq|f(x+h)-f_n(x+h)|+|f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)-f(x)|$$
$$\quad\quad<\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3}$$
$$\quad\quad=\epsilon$$
[generalization of $\epsilon, x, \delta, y$ results in (3), allowing them to conclude]
This proves that $f$ is continuous at $x$.


when you do instantiation of either $\epsilon-s, \delta-s, x-s, y-s, n-s$, are they of existential instantiation or some of them are for universal instantiation?  I don't mean to be pedantic, I just feel that we have as you say the statement that need to be proved: $\forall x \in [a,b],\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, \forall y \in [a,b], |y-x| < \delta \implies |f(y) - f(x)| < \epsilon$, the $\epsilon_i-s, x-s, y-s, n-s$ should follow the rule for universal generalization, while $\delta_j$ follows existential generalization. Now because $\epsilon$ and $\delta$....

...have to satisfy the conditions:  $(1)$ $f_n$ are all continuous on $[a,b]$: $\forall n_1\in\Bbb N, \forall x_1\in [a,b], \forall\epsilon_1 > 0,\exists \delta_1 > 0, \\forall y_1\in [a,b], |y_1-x_1| < \delta_1 \implies |f_{n_1}(y_1) - f_{n_1}(x_1)| < \epsilon_1\tag{1}$, and $(2)$ ${f_n}$ converges uniformly to $f$: $$\forall \epsilon_2 > 0,\exists N_2 \in \Bbb N, \forall x_2 \in [a,b], \forall n_2 \ge N, |f_{n_2}(x_2) - f(x_2)| < \epsilon_2\tag{2}$. Then the $\epsilon_i-s, x-s, y-s, n-s$ and $\delta_j$ get the instantiation rule of inference.  But all of them begun from...

...either universal and existential generalizations, so when they get instantiated, do $\epsilon_i-s, x-s, y-s, n-s$ and $\delta_j$ get treated as if they are now part of the hypothesis and we apply universal instantiation rule of inference to $\epsilon_i-s, x-s, y-s, n-s$ and existential instantiation rule of inference to $\delta_j$?  Can you added to/edit your answer in your reply if it is not too much trouble.  The reason I am so hung up on this is in many proof writing texts, the author never talk about this subtle point.  Say when you instantiate....

...$\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2=\epsilon_3=\frac{\epsilon}{3}$.  But by universal generalization, $\epsilon$ was assumed to be arbitrary, then instantiation would mean that, in particular, it is true for three of the $\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ when the three are summed to get back $\epsilon$ according to some criteria that needs to be satisfied in a definition, and this is what one does for universal instantiation.  I might be wrong in how I am understanding what us going in when a variable under a quantifer scope in a rule of inference gets broken up to be instantiated.

Please stop using $-s$ in mathjax to denote plurals. It looks instead like you are for reason subtracting a quantity called $s$ from each of the variables. I was starting to ask what the heck that was about when I finally guessed what you really meant. Why are you wasting time asking for confirmation of something that is completely obvious? There is no "I feel". They are clearly indicated as univerally or existentially quantized. It has nothing to do with "rules of inference" or "hypotheses" or the like "$\forall$" is universal quantization, $\exists$" is existential quantization". Enough said

Stop trying to make things as complicated as you can, and you will find that it is actually very straightforward.
